# Application is getting crashed when I drag the dialog box created through MFC because of DDX mechanism

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, ddx

I am able to fix the bug I got but I am interested in the reason behind the bug.

I used my combo box (which was created using DDX mechanism) pointer as argument in one of my method.

For example:

```
bool CMyStuff::FillCombo(CComboBox* combo_ctrl)
```

But my combo box is generated by drag and drop, MFC by default created an object instead of pointer. As I required a pointer to send, I changed that member variable to a pointer.

But after this I got compilation error as DDX does not takes pointer as an input. So changed my DDX code from:

```
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO1, m_ptr_combo1);
```

to

```
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO1, *m_ptr_combo1);
```

Now application compiled successfully and when I launch my application the dialog has also shown properly. (Note: usually dialog will be shown at the center of the desktop but this time it shown at the left top corner).

Now when I drag my dialog or do anything, application is getting crashed.

When I changed this whole declaration and sent a reference instead of pointer, my application is working properly. Can anybody explain the reasons behind this behavior?

Comment: Where does it crash ? Use the debugger to find out. Then edit your question and show  us the relevant code.

Comment: Show at least the code where you call `FillCombo(CComboBox* combo_ctrl)`.

Comment: It is crashed inside app class. Where I initiate my Dialog. Debugger is not going inside dialog class even. Unfortunately there is not much code to show. But I will try to present as much code as possible to show. Thank you.

Comment: If it crashes inside your app class, then it's interesting. The call stack is also interesting. Without more context and information it's hard to answer your question. You also should [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems to me you declared `m_combo_ptr` as a pointer inside your class and it should not be a pointer... How is it defined?